# Operating Opscenter on amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have installed Cassandra DSE 4.7 on AmazonEc2 m3.large instance.Cassandra is working normally, i have installed Opscenter 5.2 on the same node it also satisfies hardware requirements.

After installation tried to reach the ops-center through web browser.
[used procedure in the link1](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/install/opscInstallRHEL_t.html) .

I am getting connection timed out.Tried using both public and private Ip's
error image -[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiUVq.jpg).

Do i need to install datastax agents again link-[3](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/install/installingAgents.html).

Do i need to change any configuration settings.

But i have already started datastax agent when i started Cassandra link-[4](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/startStop/refDseServ.html).

Comment: you're hitting the box where opscenter is installed on port 8888?

Comment: yes @phact. I was trying to access  the node where my ops-center is installed. Any chance that this issue is because of  the firewall? or any other port settings . I couldn't figure out why exactly.

Comment: Yes.Firewall might be the issue.Can you please try turn it off or make sure the port is open and then try? You can simply test whether the ip-address and port is accessible or not from your machine, using telnet utility.

Comment: If curl localhost:8888 gives you HTML locally, then it's your firewall.

Comment: Hai @phact i have used the command   curl -Is localhost:8888 | head -1 , i got  response as  HTTp/1.1 302 FOUND which means   performing URL redirection. Does this mean my instance is able to redirect to Opscenter locally?? I have also changed security settings as [link][https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html]

Comment: @phact-- Even changing security settings i couldn't ping the AmazonEc2 instance from my IP and couldn't ping my IP from Amazon EC2. But i was able to ping google from my Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: I have checked  ports using nmap and it shows they are open(port 22 and 8888) but for 8888 i am getting service as sun-answerbook.Hello @Abhinandan can you once check the above comments, i wasn't able to add more than one reference in a comment.

Comment: Have you tested it using telnet?

Comment: hi @Abhinandan i tried connecting using telnet , i got connection timed out. Now i have deployed one more instance on cloud, even i couldn't ping from one instance to another instance.

Comment: So can you "turn off the firewall" on  that instance, which will open all ports and allow all traffic.

Comment: Have you tried that? If yes, did it help?

Comment: I have tried disabling firewall and I got access denied I tried disabling using iptables and systemtcl both got denied message. so I am trying to change the security group on cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to Create an EC2 security group with setting in the link [Security](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/install/installAMIsecurity.html) and couple of node restarts, helped me to connect to Opscenter.